"Democrat Party" = deliberate needling or natural colloqial speech?
The major American political party is called "The Democratic Party".  Their adversaries, the Republicans, think that calling them "The Democrat Party" scores feces-hurling points.
Democrats have largely stopped correcting this needling attempt - but is it possible that for some people it is just a relaxed pronunciation of the official name of the party?

No.
The genesis of "Democrat Party" is the speeches of various right-wing Republicans. Of course, it isn't grammatically correct, and it isn't about relaxed speech, since no one ever talks about the "Republic Party", equally "relaxed". Nor does one ever see Democrats using it self-referentially except to object.
